# Save data into local json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a basic form with some input fields. I want to save the form data into a json file on submitting the form.

The format of the data from form is:

```
{"name":"Sree","email":"sree@hmail.com","phone":"123456789"}
```

I have an existing JSON file named contact.json

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "name":"Noob Here",
            "email":"myemail@server.com",
            "phone":"123456"
        },
        {
            "name":"Newbie There",
            "email":"hisemail@server.com",
            "phone":"589433"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the function that i use to make data as json:

```
function submit_form(){
    var data=(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
    return false;
}

$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
    });
    return o;
};
```

I have tried inserting this code into the submit_form function

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST', 
       dataType: 'json', 
       url: 'contact.json', 
       data: data, 
       success: function(data) { 
           alert(data.message); 
       },
       failure: function (data) {
           alert('Please try again');
       }
    });
```

I'm new with json and have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Where is the location of the json file? in client/server

Comment: I'm just working on a sample so the json file is with the html file. Just old-school sample

Comment: where it should be saved? in client/server

Comment: I have an HTMl file and json file inside a folder. HTML consist of these codes. I want to save into the same json file which is in the same folder as HTML. In server

Comment: If you want save the file in server, you need to use a server side tool like java servlet, php etc. If you want to save it in the client side you may have use the HTML5 File API

Comment: K. Thanx.So I can write into a json file without server side tools na.

Comment: @ArunPJohny can you guide me how to us HTML5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i known the saving the data into local Json will not be possible by pure javascript or jquery.
If you want to save json in server side use server side programming like java or php otherwise use HTML5 for client side.

as suggested by [Arun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)